# how to incorporate the same line using sql in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
NIK     IN/OUT             DATE 
10026   1        2015-07-07 14:15:09.000
10026   0        2015-07-06 14:16:28.000
10026   1        2015-07-06 14:16:37.000
10026   0        2015-07-08 05:26:17.000
```

i want the result like below:

```
NIK     DATE IN                     DATE OUT
10026   2015-07-07 14:15:09.000       null
10026   2015-07-06 14:16:28.000   2015-07-06 14:16:37.000
10026   null                      2015-07-08 05:26:17.000
```

how to incorporate the same line based on field (in-out) using sql in sql server ?

Comment: Why `2015-07-06 14:16:37.000` has 1 and recorded as Date OUT, but `2015-07-07 14:15:09.000 ` has also 1 and recorded as Date IN? Why did you tag it as MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare @test Table
(
     NIK            Int
    ,InOut          Bit
    ,Date           Datetime
)

Insert Into @test(NIK,InOut,Date) Values
 (10026,1,'2015-07-07 14:15:09.000')
,(10026,0,'2015-07-06 14:16:28.000')
,(10026,1,'2015-07-06 14:16:37.000')
,(10026,0,'2015-07-08 05:26:17.000')


Select  t.NIK,[0] As DateIn,[1] As DateOut
From    (
            Select   t.NIK
                    ,t.InOut
                    ,Max(t.Date) As Date
                    ,Dateadd(D, 0, Datediff(D, 0, t.Date)) As OnlyDate
            From    @test As t
            Group BY Dateadd(D, 0, Datediff(D, 0, t.Date))
                    ,t.NIK
                    ,t.InOut
        ) As t
        PIVOT
        (
            Min(t.Date)
            For InOut In ([0],[1])
        ) As t
```

**Output:-**

[image]

i think, there could be a issue with 0/1 in your data.

Comment: Why did you assume that there is only one in/out combination per day?

Comment: Even if not, then also need to take Min DateIn and Max Dateout for a particular Date and NIK, and then need to produce pivot. But if enduser wants to display in-out of the whole day, then above query will not work. But such requirement should be mentioned in question.